# The true meaning of Avogadro's law...?

Tags: temperature, ideal-gas, gas

We start with the ideal gas law:

$V=\frac{nTR}{P}$

We  know that $V$ increases when $T$ increases and $V$ decreases when $P$ increases **but this only in the formula**. In fact in the reality the pression doesn't change the volume, because the pression is changed by the volume and temperature. The pression is the quantity of shocks against the "walls" of the gas, so it changes only when we compress the gas or when we increase the temperature, in fact the velocity of the particles increases and there are more shocks. In a mathematical law, we say that the pression changes the volume only because there is a proportionality, but in the reality, like we saw a moment ago, it isn't so.

Now look at the Avogadro's law:

> Same volumes of different gases contain the same number of particles **at the same temperature and pression**

Consider two volumes, $V1$ and $V2$, which are equal, so $V1 = V2$ and of course $n$ is the same

$V1=\frac{nT1R}{P1}$

$V2=\frac{nT2R}{P2}$

$\frac{nT1R}{P1}$$=$$\frac{nT2R}{P2}$

$\frac{T1}{P1}$$=$$\frac{T2}{P2}$

That means that temperature and pression don't have to be the same, but $\frac{T1}{P1}$ and $\frac{T2}{P2}$ have to be the same. Furthermore, the two volumes have to be constant, it is like two gases are contained in two blocks of the same volume and they can't expand. In fact, if the gases can expand, it doesn't value the previous relationship between temperature and pression, because if $T1$ is doubled than $T2$, **in the reality** $V1$ is doubled than $V2$, **so the numbers of particles is doubled**, and the **two pressions are costant because the increase of volume balances the increase of temperature**. In a formula:

$2*V1=\frac{n*2T1R}{P1}$

$V2=\frac{nT2R}{P2}$

However, in algebra nothing changes.

So, we can say that Avogadro created his law with costant volumes because, if the volumes could expand, the numbers of particles were different. Also we can say that the **relationship between temperature and pression** has to be the same. If Avogadro didn't create the law with costant volumes but with costant pression, then the temperature and the pression have to be the same to get the same numbers of particles, not their relationship.

Well, is my reasoning right? What do you think about it?

Comment: Avogado's law doesn't say anything about walls or containers. Gases can expand in free space. The volume strictly applies to the size of the space the gas occupies. But in working with gases we often constrain or control that space using a container. And sometimes we can vary that volume, for example in a syringe.

Comment: I'm very unsure what you're trying to say exactly.  A lot of the reasoning does not seem to be entirely true.  "Pression" is usually called "pressure" in English, if you want to edit it to make it more consistent.

Comment: -1. Not clear what you are asking. After some algebra all that you seem to be saying is that Avogadro's Law (equal volumes of gas at the same temperature and pressure) would also be true for equal pressures of gas with the same volume and temperature. But that is what the Law says anyway : if $p, V, T$ are the same, the number of particles is the same. You are just putting $p, V, T$ in a different order. ... The Ideal Gas Law is more general anyway : the gases can have different values of $p, V, T$ but if the ratio $pV/T$ is the same then the number of particles is also the same.

Comment: @sammy gerbill why -1? In the question I said that T/P has to be costant. I didn't say that T and P have to be the same, but T/P because the gases are contained and they can't expand. Did you understand me?

Comment: @docscience in fact I said that the gases are contained

Comment: The -1 is because you are not asking about something you do not understand or are confused about. You are just asking us to agree with you or point out any mistake in your reasoning. It is an unnecessarily long question, the intention being no more than to point out that the ideal gas law is more general than Avogadro's Law.

Comment: @sammy gerbill I said that the definition which I wrote is quite wrong

Comment: The definition you wrote is **not** wrong. Avogadro's Law does not say that it is **necessary** for $p, V, T$ to be the same. It says that **if** they are the same **then** $n$ is also the same.

Comment: @sammygerbil right! That's what I tried, in a more concise manner, to illustrate in my answer. But more generally there are *many* states of $P$, $V$, and $T$ that can be maintained with the same $n$.

Comment: This is a good question because: Considering the "kinetic" theory of gas, it is not evident at all that temperature and pressure are any different from each other, as so called kinetic theory says that heat lies in the impulse.  The question seems to ask about how "a wall" that measures pressure relates to temperature,; frankly, it makes me  speculate about "volume" being restricted by the same "coercive force" that defines the speed of light (heat not kinetics, but wave). Thus I hold  "Relation between Boltzmann's constant k and Avogadro's number?" a  related question.

Answer (score 0):

Avogado's law doesn't say anything about walls or containers. Gases can expand in free space. The volume strictly applies to the size of the space the gas occupies. His law simply says you can expect to see (Avogadro's number of) particles in a volume under STP conditions if the gas can be considered ideal.

$$n_A=\frac{RT_{stp}}{P_{stp} 22.4 l}$$

No matter what the gas is.

But in working with gases we often constrain or control that space using a container. And sometimes we can vary that volume, for example in a syringe. So we could start with a 22.4 liter syringe, gas inside at STP and reduce the syringe volume to 11. liters for example. The number of particles remain the same. But you no longer have STP conditions. If the walls are insulating (no heat transfer) then the pressure and temperature must both increase, but the ratio $T/P$ must be half of what you started with.

You can calculate what T & P will be using the first law (conservation of energy) and the heat capacities of the gas.

Comment: T/P has to be the same if we consider costant the volume

Comment: @Curio Agreed. But in my example with the syringe, the volume is NOT constant. It decreases to half the original volume. Since the number of particles is the same, the ratio T/P has to change.

Comment: Of course because we have P1 which is doubled of P2 and so V1 is half of V2. In this case temperature is constant

Comment: @Curio but to keep temperature constant and not transfer heat outside the control boundary you need additional constraints, mechanisms. *How* you compress the gas matters. And you usually need more physics (equations) to predict what pressure and temperature will do.

Comment: But with algebra temperature is costant

Comment: In 1/2 V = (TRn)/2P and V = (TRn)/P the temperature is constant

Comment: @Curio Not necessarily. There are more physics involved than just the ideal gas equation. How you make the changes, heat transfer will ultimately determine isothermal conditions. In my work we specially engineer 'mechanical' test lungs by introducing copper wool into the space where gas compression occurs and use insulating walls to help force the process to be isothermal. There is heat transfer, but maintained within the control volume.

Comment: @Curio in other words there are other equations to consider. And realize the state equation (ideal gas equation) is a steady state solution. It does not necessarily consider transient states when there is heat flowing.